# Can css / bootstrap be made to systematically ignore script tags?

Tags: css, ember.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

## Problem

As demonstrated in http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EGEVElIR/3, `<script>` tags interferes with bootstraps function (or to be specific, probably the css-selectors of bootstrap).

#### Bootstrap CSS code causing the problem

```
.list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}
.list-group-item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
```

## Primary questions

1. Can bootstrap systematically be modified to ignore all script tags? (Motivation: It would make use of ember.js with bootstrap trouble-free)
2. If 1. is positively answered, how would it be done best?

## Bonus questions

1. Assumption check: script tags are never actually meant to be styled, right?
2. If not already existing, should CSS language have a feature to ignore all tags of given kind? Or maybe be made to always ignore certain kinds like the script tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common problem. Checkout this issue https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/623

To answer your questions

1. No, not systematically
2. But for individual cases you could use `:first-child-of-type` instead of `:first-child`

Bonus Questions

1. You should never do anything with the script tags and I've never seen anyone do anything with them.
2. I'm not sure. It would help in this use case but it might be a pretty unique situation.

Comment: can :first-child-of-type specify that it should be the first-child that is NOT of the type script?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that its not possible.